# SQL-Server: Is there a SQL script that I can use to determine the progress of a SQL Server backup or restore process?

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

When I backup or restore a database using MS SQL Server Management Studio, I get a visual indication of how far the process has progressed, and thus how much longer I still need to wait for it to finish. If I kick off the backup or restore with a script, is there a way to monitor the progress, or do I just sit back and wait for it to finish (hoping that nothing has gone wrong?)

**Edited:** My need is specifically to be able to monitor the backup or restore progress completely separate from the session where the backup or restore was initiated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. If you have installed [sp_who2k5](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2256/spwho-for-sql-2005-spwho2k5/) into your master database, you can simply run:

```
sp_who2k5 1,1
```

The resultset will include all the active transactions. The currently running backup(s) will contain the string "BACKUP" in the **requestCommand** field. The aptly named **percentComplete** field will give you the progress of the backup.

Note: sp_who2k5 should be a part of everyone's toolkit, it does a lot more than just this.

Comment: Beware the weird quotes in the code for sp_who2k5!! Had to replace ’ with ' to get this working

Comment: I realize this is a very old thread but the link to get the stored proc is dead.

Answer (score 255):

I found this sample script [here](http://sql-articles.com/scripts/estimated-time-for-backup-restore/) that seems to be working pretty well:

```sql
SELECT 
   r.session_id
 , r.command
 , CONVERT(NUMERIC(6,2), r.percent_complete) AS [Percent Complete]
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms,r.estimated_completion_time,GetDate()),20) AS [ETA Completion Time]
 , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2), r.total_elapsed_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [Elapsed Min]
 , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2), r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0) AS [ETA Min]
 , CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2), r.estimated_completion_time/1000.0/60.0/60.0) AS [ETA Hours]
 , CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), 
      (SELECT SUBSTRING(text,r.statement_start_offset/2, CASE WHEN r.statement_end_offset = -1 
                                                             THEN 1000 
                                                             ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2 
                                                        END)
        FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
       )
   ) AS [SQL]
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r 
 WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE')
```

Comment: Provided source link is not pointing to the article anymore. This is the updated one: http://sql-articles.com/scripts/estimated-time-for-backup-restore/

Comment: Even though the restore has been going on for 15 minutes, it simply records 0% progress.  It is a large database (80 gigs).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: @user63141; the restore starts with a file allocation. If you have not done anything, then Instant File Initialization is not allowed (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx). It can take quite a while, if you have old disks or a large database

Comment: There are no rows in the output when I executed this query

Comment: I think, If you add ' RESTORE HEADERON' to the list in the WHERE clause, you will get progress on any backup verification jobs runnning afterwards as well.

Answer (score 18):

If you know the sessionID then you can use the following:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = 62
```

Or if you want to narrow it down:

```
SELECT command, percent_complete, start_time FROM sys.dm_exec_requests WHERE session_id = 62
```

Comment: This actually worked well for me

SELECT command, percent_complete, start_time FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where command = 'RESTORE DATABASE'

Answer (score 16):

Here's a simple script that generally does the trick for me:

```
SELECT command, percent_complete,total_elapsed_time, estimated_completion_time, start_time
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE')
```

Answer (score 7):

> **[Script to check the Backup and Restore progress in SQL Server](https://alwayssql.wordpress.com/2018/03/10/query-to-check-the-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/):**

Many times it happens that your backup (or restore) activity has been started by another Database Administrator or by a job, and you cannot use the GUI anything else to check the progress of that Backup / Restore.

By combining multiple commands, I have generated below script which can give us a summary of current backups and restores which are happening on the server.

```
select 
r.session_id, 
r.blocking_session_id, 
db_name(database_id) as [DatabaseName],
r.command, 
[SQL_QUERY_TEXT] = Substring(Query.TEXT, (r.statement_start_offset / 2) + 1, (
            (
                CASE r.statement_end_offset
                    WHEN - 1
                        THEN Datalength(Query.TEXT)
                    ELSE r.statement_end_offset
                    END - r.statement_start_offset
                ) / 2
            ) + 1),
                [SP_Name] =Coalesce(Quotename(Db_name(Query.dbid)) + N'.' + Quotename(Object_schema_name(Query.objectid, Query.dbid)) + N'.' + 
     Quotename(Object_name(Query.objectid, Query.dbid)), ''),
r.percent_complete,
start_time,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(ms, [estimated_completion_time],
GETDATE()), 20) AS [ETA_COMPLETION_TIME],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.[total_elapsed_time] / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [Elapsed_MIN],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.[estimated_completion_time] / 1000.0 / 60.0) AS [Remaning_ETA_MIN],
CONVERT(NUMERIC(6, 2), r.[estimated_completion_time] / 1000.0 / 60.0/ 60.0) AS [ETA_Hours],
wait_type,
wait_time/1000 as Wait_Time_Sec, 
wait_resource
from sys.dm_exec_requests r 
cross apply sys.fn_get_sql(r.sql_handle) as Query where r.session_id>50 and command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG', 'BACKUP LOG')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT session_id as SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
```

Answer (score 5):

Try wih :

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where command like '%BACKUP%'

SELECT command, percent_complete, start_time FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where command like '%BACKUP%'

SELECT command, percent_complete,total_elapsed_time, estimated_completion_time, start_time
  FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
  WHERE command IN ('RESTORE DATABASE','BACKUP DATABASE')
```

Answer (score 4):

Use STATS in the BACKUP command if it is just a script.

Inside code it is a bit more complicated.  In ODBC for example, you set SQL_ATTR_ASYNC_ENABLE and then look for SQL_STILL_EXECUTING return code, and do some repeated calls of SQLExecDirect until you get a SQL_SUCCESS (or eqiv).

Answer (score 3):

Use STATS option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx

Comment: Unless I am missing something, this limits me to get the feedback in the same session as the one where I start the backup.  In our case we kick off a DB restore with a scheduled BAT file at 4 in the morning and I want to connect to the server 3 or 4 hours later and determine the progress.

Comment: I think you can redirect script output to the log file and then examine it from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to find out how your restore or backup progress is by the following query:

```
USE[master]
GO
SELECT session_id AS SPID, command, a.text AS Query, start_time, percent_complete, dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time 
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a 
        WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE','RESTORE DATABASE')
GO
```

The query above, identify the session by itself and perform a percentage progress every time you press F5 or Execute button on SSMS!

The query was performed by the guy who write this [post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  session_id as SPID, command, start_time, percent_complete,
        dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as estimated_completion_time,
        a.text AS Query 
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests r CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) a
WHERE r.command in ('BACKUP DATABASE', 'BACKUP LOG', 'RESTORE DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG')
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `STATS=10` or `STATS=1` in backup command.

```
BACKUP DATABASE [xxxxxx] TO  DISK = N'E:\\Bachup_DB.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  
NAME = N'xxxx-Complète Base de données Sauvegarde', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION,  STATS = 10
GO.
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone running SQL Server on RDS (AWS), there's a [built-in procedure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Poll) callable in the `msdb` database which provides comprehensive information for all backup and restore tasks:

```
exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;
```

This will give a full rundown of each task, its configuration, details about execution (such as completed percentage and total duration), and a `task_info` column which is immensely helpful when trying to figure out what's wrong with a backup or restore.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when working on Database restore operation on MS SQL Server 2012.

However, for my own scenario, I just needed to see the progress of the **DATABASE RESTORE** operation in the script window

All I had to do was add the STATS option to the script:

```
USE master;
GO

ALTER DATABASE mydb SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
    
RESTORE DATABASE mydb
    FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\my_db_21-08-2020.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
         STATS = 10,
         RESTART,
    MOVE 'my_db' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\my_db.mdf',
    MOVE 'my_db_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mydb_log.ldf'
GO
    
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

And then I switched to the **Messages** tab of the Script window to see the progress of the **DATABASE RESTORE** operation:

[image]

If you want to get more information **after** the DATABASE RESTORE operation you can use this command suggested by [eythort](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1934989/eythort):

```
SELECT command, percent_complete, start_time FROM sys.dm_exec_requests where command = 'RESTORE DATABASE'
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the backup or restore progress completely separate from the session where the backup or restore was initiated. No third party tools required. Tested on Microsoft SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT percent_complete, *
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
WHERE command In ( 'RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using sp_whoisactive, very informative an basically industry standard. it returns percent complete as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the following to get a detail reports on MS SQL for your restore progress-

`exec msdb.dbo.rds_task_status;`

Answer (score -1):

simply run bkp_status on master db you will get backup status