# Restoring SQL Server 2008 R2 backup to SQL Server 2014 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are working to archive and store a set of SQL Server databases that exist on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance on server A (which will be decommissioned). The goal is to backup (and compress) all databases and migrate them to server B (data warehousing server). Server B is running SQL Server 2014.

I have completed all the migration and now I am attempting to test the restore of one of the databases to make sure we can restore them if needed on server B.

When I attempt to restore using the restore wizard in server B, the restore starts but in checking the progress of the restore, it never moves past 0%. It just keeps trying to restore.

Any idea what maybe going on?

Comment: What is the SQL you're using to complete the Restore?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a SQL script that I can use to determine the progress of a SQL Server backup or restore process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152447/is-there-a-sql-script-that-i-can-use-to-determine-the-progress-of-a-sql-server-b) The DB may be very, very large, or the restore particularly slow (because your backup medium is, for example). Ask the wizard to script the `RESTORE` statement instead of executing it directly, and use `STATS = 1` to report progress by single percents.

Comment: After some further investigation, I seemed to have resolved my issue. The following article discussed the same issue I was experiencing.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/194809d0-c96e-4c7f-8fce-ce95fc7f9663/sql-restore-stays-at-0-continues-executing-and-never-progresses?forum=sqlexpress

The final post talks about stopping the restore and restarting it. I attempted that and the restore completed in 30 minutes (47 GB uncompressed DB), showing progress within a few seconds.

Not sure if this is a bug with SQL Server 2014 but it does seem to be a global issue.

Comment: @user10141019 - you should post this as an answer (you CAN answer your own questions) and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

After some further investigation, I seemed to have resolved my issue. The following article discussed the same issue I was experiencing.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/194809d0-c96e-4c7f-8fce-ce95fc7f9663/sql-restore-stays-at-0-continues-executing-and-never-progresses?forum=sqlexpress

The final post talks about stopping the restore and restarting it. I attempted that and the restore completed in 30 minutes (47 GB uncompressed DB), showing progress within a few seconds. Not sure if this is a bug with SQL Server 2014 but it does seem to be a global issue.